# Шейдеры в unity3d

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Рискуя нахватать по шапке, я все таки задам этот вопрос.

Встала необходимость написать шейдер для *Unity3d*, казалось бы простейший, радиально проявляющееся изображение (как на gif ниже), но с эффектами блюра и градиентной прозрачности. То есть кусок сегмента (например градусов 30), который  заполняет изображение - не резко видимый, а с плавным переходом прозрачности (пример на рисунке ниже).

При этом изображение при нулевой прозрачности имеет максимальную заблюренность (хоть на прозрачном и не видно, да и на этом примере не очень понятно, но т.к. при использовании шейдер будет применяться на переходах между фото, то там будет все четко видно) и по мере того, как прозрачность отдельно взятых пикселей уменьшается, уменьшается и степень блюра на них. Таким образом там, где прозрачность 100 (непрозрачный), там блюр = 0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитав несколько статей все же никак не могу разложить по полочкам это все в голове. Прочитал как именно реализуется размытие по гауссу (усреднение значение rgb ближайших пикселей на спрайте по каждому столбцу/линии), понимаю что к этому необходимо прицепить прозрачность и менять одно в зависимости от другого, но, например, как это все сделать, непосредственно в коде, прицепив еще и анимацию сюда, абсолютно не понимаю (хотя и понимаю что есть св-во `_TransVal` есть параметр `#pragma alpha`, который за прозрачность отвечает).

Т.к. писать шейдеры не приходилось ранее и, если честно, те статьи, что нашел в инете, не сильно внесли ясности - именно в вопрос реализации. Cамо понимание что такое шейдер, какие они бывают и зачем - у меня присутствует.

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь возьмется поэтапно расписать на примере моей задачи процесс реализации с пояснениями: мол нам нужно это для этого, а это для этого, вот так мы будем изменять блюр, вот так прозрачность, а вот так анимацию присобачим.

**UPDATE**
Чего я смог добиться: Регулируя значения sigma и cutoff собранного мною в бреду непонимания (в силу отсутствия опыта в написании шейдеров) происходит все то что мне необходимо кроме одного НО, спрайт позади всего этого откуда он и как от него избавиться я так и не смог понять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://g.recordit.co/rUaGYdynQ3.gif (картинка в большем разрешении).

Данный материал (с шейдером) применен на *image*. *image* и *canvas* в котором они находятся вынесены на слой *transparentfx* который рендерит отдельная камера (на основной отключен этот слой). Осталось понять как отключить (или убрать из рендера) этот спрайт позади и в минимальном виде задача будет решена (прозрачность на краю заполнения уже не суть важно хотя бы с блюром разобраться).

**UPDATE 2** задача решается если выставить на самом `Image` type `filled` и крутить ручку `fill amount`. Но остается непонятным, как по-человечески отключить рендер image'a, оставив рендер только того, что есть.

Результат работы шейдера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE от 29 декабря**
Поняв что с написанием по человечески у меня все не очень, я попробовал использовать Shader Forge и в нем вроде бы добился необходимого эффекта (одного из необходимых). Но получилось очень странно, в том смысле что в окне инспектора в юнити эффект отображался как надо а в сцене гейм он вел себя "упрощенно" так сказать. Смотри гиф ниже для лучшего понимания.
Гиф1, окно инспектора.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Гиф2, окно игры[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятно, у вас есть уже написанный шейдер или нет?) Просто через скрипт обратиться к полю, ответственного за прозрачность или что-либо другое - легко... но если нет самого шейдера, то еще и описывать что там должно быть - как-то не камильфо)  а еще непонятно это хотите применять на 3d объекте но снятого в 2d или на спрайте? или на lineRendere каком-нибудь? Это будет во многих местах применимо или в одном единственном. Если в единственном, то проще не через шейдер сделать а спрайтом (если в 2d)

Comment: Шейдерам у меня нету. Хотя из костылей и палок по интернету уже насобирал почти все что надо. Шейдеры будет применяться на текстурах, то есть на отдельно взятые 2d изображения.

Comment: К сожалению нет времени что-то написать-ответить, но, я бы рекомендовал продублировать вопрос на enSO или https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ а также на русский форм по юнити http://unity3d.ru/distribution/index.php и ответ, если получите,  потом опубликовать тут тоже. Вопрос интересный. Особенно, что шейдер к спрайту, а не к 3в модели..... Кстати, могу порекомендовать для шейдеров найти (бесплатно найти ) и поиграться с Shader Forge - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14147  .....  http://acegikmo.com/shaderforge/wiki/index.php?title=UV_Rotation_%26_Panning

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо обязательно посмотрю. Я все эти дни ковырял так или иначе шейдеры  и почти сумел добиться нужного мне результата. Ключевое слово ПОЧТИ :) Я кстати продублировал вопрос (в упрощенном виде) на answers.unity3d.com но и там ответа пока не получил, упрощение в том что хотя бы получить эффект как image типа filled только с дополнительной прозрачностью на грани которая заполняет спрайт как  у меня на первой картинке (надеюсь понятно объяснил) :)

Comment: Странно, вы говорите что хотели получить эффект как image типа filled только с дополнительной прозрачностью, но вопрос проапдейтели и применяете уже к картинкам канваса эффект. Так что же в итоге надо: к простым спрайтам применять или всё же к изображениям холста?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А стоит все это через единый шейдер городить? 
Делал бы так:

1. Чтобы использовать разблуреное изображение вам понадобиться еще одна
   камера которая через постэффект BLUR будет писать в RenderTexture
   экран без накладываемого изображения(поместите его в отдельный Layer
   и в этой камере этот слой выключите).
2. Далее делаем анимацию проявления любой формы которая вас интересует.
   Cделайте форму с анимированием маски по альфе.
3. А дальше уже все просто, для анимированной формы используем
   простейший материал который в зависимости от прозрачности текстуры
   на материале рисует через смешение либо с основной текстуры либо с
   размытой в RenderTexture.

Comment: В общем что делал в итоге я. Написал шейдер который в 2 паса первым блюрит вторым делает катоф по радиальной альфе. Все это в отдельный слой и на отдельную камеру что бы отделить от основного изображения. Проблема была в том что нужное мне изображение блюрилось, при помощи катофа заполнялось, но за ним висел еще один абсолютно чистенький спрайт, Откуда он брался я так и не смог понять.

Comment: У вас на камере есть параметр ClearFlag. В зависимости от того что в нем выбрано и какова очередь отрисовки в эту камеру попадает что-то на задний фон.

Comment: @justyx интересно, а этот  ответ помог решить проблему? А то я что-то  без визуального представления не очень понял как это всё происходит и причем без использования Canvas UI....... Может кто-то как-то это наглядно показать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этот способ работает для любой камеры, а не только при работе с UI. Данный подход применяется в одном из наших проектов, где приходится смешивать несколько сцен с разными эффектами и псевдо генерируемым изображением

Comment: @KingPeas я уже с автором поговорил, да и в обновление вопроса посмотрел и понял о чем речь была и прочие нюансы))

Answer (score 4):

## Ответ, часть 2.

- Так как возможно это будет нагрузка на шейдер, то можно некоторые части также довыносить в управляющий скрипт. Оставить тут только применение значений. В итоге шейдер и скрипт могут быть такими:

  ```
  Shader "Custom/RadialFill_MoreScriptControl" {
      Properties {
          [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("MainTex", 2D) = "white" {}
          _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
          _OpacityRotator ("Opacity Rotator", Range(-360, 360)) = -360 // два полных оборота
          _TextureRotator ("Texture Rotator", Range(0, 360)) = 360
          [MaterialToggle] _FillClockwise ("Fill Clockwise", int ) = 1
          [HideInInspector]_Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
          [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0            
          [HideInInspector] _CutoffRightBottomLeftTop ("cRBLT", Float) = 1.0
          [HideInInspector] _OpRightBottomLeftTop ("oRBLT", Float) = 1.0  
          [HideInInspector] _OpVector ("OpVector", Vector) = (1, -1, 0, 0)
          [HideInInspector] _ReverseMaskCoords ("_ReverseMaskCoords", int) = 0 
      }

      SubShader {
          Tags {
              "IgnoreProjector"="True"
              "Queue"="Transparent"
              "RenderType"="Transparent"
              "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
              "PreviewType"="Plane"
          }

          Pass {
              Name "FORWARD"
              Tags {
                  "LightMode"="ForwardBase"
              }

              Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
              Cull Off
              ZWrite Off

              CGPROGRAM
              #pragma vertex vert
              #pragma fragment frag
              #define UNITY_PASS_FORWARDBASE
              #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON

              #include "UnityCG.cginc"
              #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase
              #pragma exclude_renderers gles3 metal d3d11_9x xbox360 xboxone ps3 ps4 psp2 
              #pragma target 3.0

              static const float TAU = float(6.283185); // это 2 * PI, кто не знает

              uniform sampler2D _MainTex; 
              uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
              uniform float4 _Color;
              uniform float _OpacityRotator;
              uniform float _TextureRotator;
              uniform fixed _FillClockwise;       
              uniform fixed _CutoffRightBottomLeftTop;
              uniform fixed _OpRightBottomLeftTop;
              uniform float2 _OpVector;
              uniform int _ReverseMaskCoords;

              struct VertexInput {
                  float4 vertex : POSITION;
                  float3 normal : NORMAL;
                  float4 tangent : TANGENT;
                  float2 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
              };

              struct VertexOutput {
                  float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                  float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                  float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
                  float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD2;
                  float3 tangentDir : TEXCOORD3;
                  float3 bitangentDir : TEXCOORD4;
              };

              // матрица вращения
              float2x2 getMatrix(float angle) {                               
                  float r_cos = cos(angle);
                  float r_sin = sin(angle);                
                  return float2x2(r_cos, -r_sin, r_sin, r_cos);
              }

              // формирование маски
              float2x2 getMask(float oAtan2MaskNormalized, float rotator, int isRotatorSubtract) {                            
                  float oAtan2MaskRotatable = isRotatorSubtract ? oAtan2MaskNormalized - rotator : rotator - oAtan2MaskNormalized;
                  return ceil(oAtan2MaskRotatable);
              }

              float getNormalizedAtanMask(float2 maskChannels, int reverseMaskCoords) {
                  float atan2var = reverseMaskCoords ? atan2(maskChannels.r, maskChannels.g) : atan2(maskChannels.g, maskChannels.r);
                  return (atan2var / TAU) + 0.5;
              }

              VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                  VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                  o.uv0 = v.texcoord0;
                  o.normalDir = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                  o.tangentDir = normalize(mul(_Object2World, float4(v.tangent.xyz, 0.0)).xyz);
                  o.bitangentDir = normalize(cross(o.normalDir, o.tangentDir) * v.tangent.w);
                  o.posWorld = mul(_Object2World, v.vertex);
                  o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex );
                  #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                      o.pos = UnityPixelSnap(o.pos);
                  #endif

                  return o;
              }

              float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                  i.normalDir = normalize(i.normalDir);                
                  float4 _MainTex_var = tex2D(_MainTex,TRANSFORM_TEX(i.uv0, _MainTex));                

                  /*** Общее начало для opacity и cutoff, помогающее переключать вращение по/против часовой стрелки BEGIN ***/
                  // float2(1, -1) - по часовой, float2(1, 1) - против часовой
                  float2 clockCounterDirection = _FillClockwise ? float2(1, -1) : float2(1, 1); 
                  // по умолчанию "обрезание" начинается слева. 
                  // умножение на -1 для того, чтоб началось справа.....просто потому, что я так хочу =)
                  float2 CommonStartAndSwitcher = (-1 * (i.uv0 - 0.5)) * clockCounterDirection;
                  /*** Общее начало для opacity и cutoff с переключателем вращения по/против часовой стрелки END ***/


                  /*** Секция для cutoff ***/
                  float tRotatorNormalized = _TextureRotator / 360.0;                 
                  float cutoffRotator_ang = _CutoffRightBottomLeftTop * -TAU;
                  float2x2 cutoffRotationMatrix = getMatrix(cutoffRotator_ang); 
                  float2 cutoffRotator = mul(CommonStartAndSwitcher, cutoffRotationMatrix);
                  float whiteToBlackMask = getMask(getNormalizedAtanMask(cutoffRotator, 0), tRotatorNormalized, 1);
                  // Финальная маска
                  float finalMask = 1.0 - whiteToBlackMask;
                  clip(finalMask - 0.5);


                  /*** Секция для opacity ***/
                  float oRotatorNormalized = _OpacityRotator / 360.0;
                  float2 oVector = float2(_OpVector);

                  float oRotator_ang = _OpRightBottomLeftTop * (oRotatorNormalized * -TAU);               
                  float2x2 oRotationMatrix = getMatrix(oRotator_ang);             
                  float2 oRotator = mul(oVector * CommonStartAndSwitcher, oRotationMatrix);
                  float oWhiteToBlackMask = getMask(getNormalizedAtanMask(oRotator, _ReverseMaskCoords), oRotatorNormalized, 0);                                                                  
                  // Финальная прозрачность 
                  float oFinalMultiply = _MainTex_var.a * max(getNormalizedAtanMask(oRotator, _ReverseMaskCoords), ceil(oWhiteToBlackMask)); 


                  /*** Излучение (Emissive) ***/
                  // oFinalMultiply чтоб обрезать прозрачную область, где она обрезана в самой текстуре
                  float3 finalColor = _MainTex_var.rgb * _Color.rgb * oFinalMultiply;
                  // Конечный результат (цвет, обработанный маской и повернутый под углом альфа канал)
                  return fixed4(finalColor, oFinalMultiply);
              }

              ENDCG
          }       
      }

      FallBack "Diffuse"    
  }
  ```

  Скрипт будет таким:

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;

  public enum FillOrigin {
      Right,
      Bottom,
      Left,
      Top
  }


  public class RadialFill_MoreScriptControl : MonoBehaviour {

      public float cutoffStartAngle = 5.0f; // градусы 
      public float opacityStartAngle = -350.0f; // градусы,  -2 * PI + 10 (небольшой начальный угол)
      public float deltaAngle = 5f;
      public bool fillClockwise = true;
      public FillOrigin fillOrigin = FillOrigin.Right;

      private const float MAX_ANGLE = 360.0f;
      private Material material;
      private float _TextureRotator; // ссылка на переменную _TextureRotator в шейдере
      private float _OpacityRotator; // ссылка на переменную _TextureRotator в шейдере

      void Start () {
          material = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
      }


      void Update () {            
          if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))       
              StartCoroutine(FillSprite());       
      }


      IEnumerator FillSprite() {      
          var cOffStart = cutoffStartAngle;
          var oStart = opacityStartAngle;
          material.SetFloat("_FillClockwise", fillClockwise ? 1 : 0);
          material.SetFloat("_TextureRotator", cOffStart);
          material.SetFloat("_OpacityRotator", oStart);

          SetCutoffData();
          SetOpacityData();

          _TextureRotator = cOffStart;
          _OpacityRotator = oStart;

          while(_OpacityRotator <= MAX_ANGLE) {           
              if (_TextureRotator >= MAX_ANGLE) 
                  _TextureRotator = MAX_ANGLE;
              if (_OpacityRotator >= MAX_ANGLE) 
                  _OpacityRotator = MAX_ANGLE;

              material.SetFloat("_TextureRotator", _TextureRotator);
              material.SetFloat("_OpacityRotator", _OpacityRotator);

              _OpacityRotator += deltaAngle;
              _TextureRotator += deltaAngle;

              yield return null;
          }

          yield break;
      }


      private void SetCutoffData() {
          var cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = 1.0f;
          if (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Bottom)
              cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = fillClockwise ? 1.75f : 1.25f;
          else if (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Left)
              cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = 1.5f;
          else if (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Top)
              cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = fillClockwise ? 1.25f : 1.75f;
          cutoffRightBottomLeftTop += 0.001f;

          material.SetFloat("_CutoffRightBottomLeftTop", cutoffRightBottomLeftTop);
      }


      private void SetOpacityData() {
          Vector2 oVector = new Vector2(1, -1);
          var oRightBottomLeftTop = 1.0f;
          int reverseMaskCoords = (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Top || fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Bottom) ? 1 : 0;
          if (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Left)
              oVector = new Vector2(-1, 1);
          else if (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Top) {
              oVector = fillClockwise ? new Vector2(-1, -1) : new Vector2(1, 1);
              oRightBottomLeftTop = -1.0f;
          } else if (fillOrigin == FillOrigin.Bottom) {
              oVector = fillClockwise ? new Vector2(1, 1) : new Vector2(-1, -1);
              oRightBottomLeftTop = -1.0f;
          }

          material.SetInt("_ReverseMaskCoords", reverseMaskCoords);
          material.SetVector("_OpVector", oVector);
          material.SetFloat("_OpRightBottomLeftTop", oRightBottomLeftTop);
      }
  }
  ```

  в инспекторе управление такое:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

И по поводу размытия...Так как мой ответ уже большой (из-за кода)...и уже вторая часть, то я приведу код шейдера `Blur`, который вы можете перенести в шейдеры выше. А также дописать управление размытием из скрипта по примеру выше.

```
Shader "Custom/Blur" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        radius ("radius", Range(0, 80)) =0
        resolution ("resolution", float) = 800
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag       
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            uniform  float resolution = 800;
            uniform  float radius = 400;
            uniform  float2 dir = float2(0,1);

            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                float4 sum = float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                float2 tc = i.uv;

                // радиус размытия в пикселях
                float blur = radius/resolution/4; 

                float hstep = 1; // размытие по горизонтали
                float vstep = 0; // размытие по вертикали


                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x - 5.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y - 5.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.0052111262;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x - 4.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y - 4.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.0162162162;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x - 3.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y - 3.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.0540540541;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x - 2.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y - 2.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.1216216216;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x - 1.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y - 1.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.1945945946;

                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x, tc.y)) * 0.2270270270;

                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x + 1.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y + 1.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.1945945946;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x + 2.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y + 2.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.1216216216;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x + 3.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y + 3.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.0540540541;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x + 4.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y + 4.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.0162162162;
                sum += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(tc.x + 5.0 * blur * hstep, tc.y + 5.0 * blur * vstep)) * 0.0052111262;

                return float4(sum.rgb, 1);
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

---

**P.S.** К сожалению шейдер `RadialFill` работает только для `Sprite Mode` → `Single`. Как сделать для мульти `Multiple`, я пока не знаю.

**P.P.S.** Можно сделать еще улучшения:

- Вынести функцию `getMatrix` (матрица вращения) также в скрипт.
- Сделать маску не генерируемой внутри шейдера, а взять текстуру в виде картинки `atan2` и применять уже её. Глядишь еще чуть снять загрузку с шейдера можно.

**P.P.P.S.** Для попытки понимая шейдеров хоть на маленком уровне можно использовать ассет [Shader Forge](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14147) - Визуальный редактор для программирования шейдеров. Визуальность в данном случае очень в плюс.

Из бесплатных пока поиск показывает только [uShader FREE](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/65839) - но его я не пробовал, не знаю на сколько хорош.

---

Ссылки к прочтению, которые использовались в шейдерах выше:

- [Стандартные шейдерные предпроцессорные макросы](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-BuiltinMacros.html)
- [Создание программ с несколькими вариантами шейдеров](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/SL-MultipleProgramVariants.html)
- [Директивы компиляции #pragma](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-ShaderPrograms.html)
- [Culling & Depth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html)
- [Блендинг (Blending)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-Blend.html)
- [Шейдеры и эффекты в Unity. Книга рецептов](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27711604/)
- [Unity 5.x Shaders and Effects Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1785285246)

Comment: а Вам случаем не известны программы по типу ShaderForge, но бесплатные? Может существуют сторонние, но с экспортом под unity?

Comment: @OlmerDale к сожалению не знаю... Я про SF сам недавно только узнал))) Если только на [assetStore](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/) копаться искать по параметру `Free Only` ну и в интернете запрашивать `unity3d visual shader editor`...... Но, думаю, такие значительные вещи бесплатными не бывают. К тому же 5 т.р. рублей за построение шейдеров не парясь с текстовыми редакторами (причем без автокомплита) для них и постоянным просмотром результатов отработки и экспериментирование с разными возможными комбинациями — по-моему цена не столько велика.

Comment: @OlmerDale по поиску бесплатных пока показывает только [uShader FREE](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/65839)

Answer (score 2):

Ух ты, интересный вопрос и даже награаадааа!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, сколько я не читал, я не смог представить зачем эффект размытия применять на прозрачности. Ведь если некая часть спрайта будет прозрачна, то размытия там итак не будет видно и заметно, а там где не прозрачно, то и размытия нет. Либо я чего не понял и имелось виду применение размытия вообще на весь спрайт, не зависимо от того, какой процент радиального заполнения сейчас имеется. Если именно так, то

1. Можно поступить так, как написано в другом ответе: взять из стандартных ассетов Юнити (благо их не мало предоставляется) эффект размытия, применяемый на камере. Добавить еще одну камеру, добавить туда скрипт размытия и шейдер и в нужный момент включать ту камеру и изменять смещение в Blur-эффекте.
2. Реализовать, как и хотели в шейдере)) Об этом в самом конце.

---

#### (!!!)

Да простят меня админы сайта, но в один ответ у меня не вместится (из-за количество кода, а не из-за "воды"). Поэтому ответ будет в двух частях.

---

## Ответ, часть 1.

Суть, что обрезки, что заливания прозрачностью будет сводиться к тому, что будет браться маска, на основе которой всё будет происходить. Маска генерируется программно через тригонометрическую функцию `atan2`. На осях она выглядит так:

[image: atan2]

В двумерной системе координат выглядит так:

[image: atan2 2D]

Так как маска — это некая компонента, состоящая из оттенков черного и белого, в которой черный цвет — полностью отсутствие текстуры, а белый — полностью видимая текстура, то для прозрачности маска `atan2` будет представлять из себя переход от черного к белому (см. рисунок выше), а для обрезки будет применена дополнительная функция, чтоб было только черное/белое, без плавных переходов.

[image: atan2 ceil]

Я попробую просто опубликовать шейдер, в котором будут комментарии того, что сделано. Не уверен, что все будет понятно, но я хоть как-то худо бедно постараюсь.

```
Shader "Custom/RadialFill" {
    Properties {
        [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("MainTex", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _OpacityRotator ("Opacity Rotator", Range(-360, 360)) = -360 // два полных оборота
        _TextureRotator ("Texture Rotator", Range(0, 360)) = 360
        [MaterialToggle] _FillClockwise ("Fill Clockwise", Float ) = 1
        [HideInInspector]_Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0    
        [KeywordEnum(Right, Bottom, Left, Top)] _Fill_Origin("Fill Origin", Int) = 0        
    }

    SubShader {
        // https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html
        Tags {      
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
        }

        Pass {
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ForwardBase" // https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PassTags.html
            }

            Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha  // https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-Blend.html      
            ZWrite Off                  // https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert     // vert - имя функции обработки вершин
            #pragma fragment frag   // frag - имя функции обработки пикселей             
            #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON

            // как работает shader_feature: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/SL-MultipleProgramVariants.html
            // он относится к свойству _Fill_Origin .... по сути - автоматически конвертируем его имя и значения в константы
            #pragma shader_feature _FILL_ORIGIN_RIGHT _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM _FILL_ORIGIN_LEFT _FILL_ORIGIN_TOP

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            #pragma exclude_renderers gles3 metal d3d11_9x xbox360 xboxone ps3 ps4 psp2 
            #pragma target 3.0
            uniform sampler2D _MainTex; 
            uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
            uniform float4 _Color;
            uniform float _OpacityRotator;
            uniform float _TextureRotator;
            uniform fixed _FillClockwise;

            static const float TAU = float(6.283185); // это 2 * PI, кто не знает

            struct VertexInput {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float4 tangent : TANGENT;
                float2 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct VertexOutput {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
                float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD2;
                float3 tangentDir : TEXCOORD3;
                float3 bitangentDir : TEXCOORD4;
            };

            VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                o.uv0 = v.texcoord0;
                o.normalDir = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                o.tangentDir = normalize(mul(_Object2World, float4(v.tangent.xyz, 0.0)).xyz);
                o.bitangentDir = normalize(cross(o.normalDir, o.tangentDir) * v.tangent.w);
                o.posWorld = mul(_Object2World, v.vertex);
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex );
                #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                    o.pos = UnityPixelSnap(o.pos);
                #endif

                return o;
            }

            float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                i.normalDir = normalize(i.normalDir);                
                float4 _MainTex_var = tex2D(_MainTex,TRANSFORM_TEX(i.uv0, _MainTex));                

                /*** Общее начало для opacity и cutoff, помогающее переключать вращение по/против часовой стрелки BEGIN ***/
                // float2(1, -1) - по часовой, float2(1, 1) - против часовой
                float2 clockCounterDirection = _FillClockwise ? float2(1, -1) : float2(1, 1); 
                // по умолчанию "обрезание" начинается слева. 
                // умножение на -1 для того, чтоб началось справа.....просто потому, что я так хочу =)
                float2 CommonStartAndSwitcher = (-1 * (i.uv0 - 0.5)) * clockCounterDirection;
                /*** Общее начало для opacity и cutoff с переключателем вращения по/против часовой стрелки END ***/


                /*** Секция для cutoff ***/
                float cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = 1.0; // изменение направления

                // В зависимости от того, что выбрано в качестве старта вращения право/лево/верх/низ
                // нужно будет провернуть и текстурку.
                // +0.25 - 90 градусов, +0.5 - 180, +0.75 - 270
                #if _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM
                    cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = _FillClockwise ? 1.75 : 1.25;
                #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_LEFT
                    cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = 1.5;
                #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_TOP
                    cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = _FillClockwise ? 1.25 : 1.75;
                #endif
                cutoffRightBottomLeftTop += 0.001;

                // Матрица вращения для cutoff
                float cutoffRotator_ang = cutoffRightBottomLeftTop * -TAU;                
                float cutoffRotator_cos = cos(cutoffRotator_ang);
                float cutoffRotator_sin = sin(cutoffRotator_ang);                
                float2x2 cutoffRotationMatrix = float2x2(cutoffRotator_cos, -cutoffRotator_sin, cutoffRotator_sin, cutoffRotator_cos);                      

                float2 cutoffRotator = mul(CommonStartAndSwitcher, cutoffRotationMatrix);

                // перевод из системы от 0 до 360 градусов в отсчет от 0 до 1
                float tRotatorNormalized = _TextureRotator / 360.0;   
                // Генерирование маски для отсечения пикселей и  отсечение пикселей по предоставленной маске
                // 1. Для генерации нужны исхоные две координаты.... 
                // rg, утрированно, представляют из себя x и y
                float2 cutoffMaskSource = cutoffRotator.rg;             
                // 2. Формируем начальную маску // в инете рисуночки глянуть как это выглядит =)
                // Угол задается в радианах и принимает значения от -PI до PI, исключая -PI
                float atan2Mask = atan2(cutoffMaskSource.g, cutoffMaskSource.r);
                // 3. Добавляем пол оборота (до целого) и конвертируем в значение от 0 до 1,
                // для дальнейшей удобной работы в единичном отрезке, т.к tRotatorNormalized меняется от 0 до 1
                float atan2MaskNormalized = (atan2Mask / TAU) + 0.5;
                // 4. Привязка маски к повороту. хз как объяснить               
                float atan2MaskRotatable = atan2MaskNormalized - tRotatorNormalized;
                // 5. Получаем карту заливки от белого к черному
                // Белый - полностью видимый участок, Черный - обрезающиеся (не отображающиеся) пиксели
                float whiteToBlackMask = ceil(atan2MaskRotatable);
                // 6. Собираем финальную маску от чёрного к белому (т.к. нужно постепенное заполнение)
                float finalMask = 1.0 - whiteToBlackMask;
                clip(finalMask - 0.5);


                /*** Секция для opacity ***/
                // oVector меняется в зависимости от начала направления - лево/право/верх/низ
                float2 oVector = float2(1, -1);
                // изменение направления в зависимости от лево-право (1.0) или верх-низ (-1.0)
                float oRightBottomLeftTop = 1.0;

                // В зависимости от того, что выбрано в качестве старта вращения право/лево/верх/низ
                // нужно будет провернуть и маску.
                #if _FILL_ORIGIN_LEFT
                    oVector = float2(-1, 1);
                #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_TOP
                    oVector = _FillClockwise ? float2(-1, -1) : float2(1, 1);
                    oRightBottomLeftTop = -1.0;
                #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM
                    oVector = _FillClockwise ? float2(1, 1) : float2(-1, -1);
                    oRightBottomLeftTop = -1.0;
                #endif

                float oRotatorNormalized = _OpacityRotator / 360.0;

                // Матрица вращения для opacity
                float oRotator_ang = oRightBottomLeftTop * (oRotatorNormalized * -TAU);                
                float oRotator_cos = cos(oRotator_ang);
                float oRotator_sin = sin(oRotator_ang);                
                float2x2 oRotationMatrix = float2x2(oRotator_cos, -oRotator_sin, oRotator_sin, oRotator_cos);               

                float2 oRotator = mul(oVector * CommonStartAndSwitcher, oRotationMatrix);

                // Как и у cutoff формируем маску
                float2 oMask = oRotator.rg;
                float2 oMaskHorizOrVert = atan2(oMask.g, oMask.r);
                // при формировании маски по вертикали, нужно поменять x, y местами в функции
                #if (_FILL_ORIGIN_TOP || _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM)
                    oMaskHorizOrVert = atan2(oMask.r, oMask.g);
                #endif

                float oAtan2MaskNormalized = (oMaskHorizOrVert / TAU) + 0.5;
                // oRotatorNormalized - oAtan2MaskNormalized для того, чтобы первый круг просто провернуться, а на втором
                // начать обрезку как у cutoff, только начиная схвоста, но при этом продолжая вращаться.
                // Если было бы  oAtan2MaskNormalized - oRotatorNormalized (как в примере с cutoff выше), то, т.к. значение oRotatorNormalized
                // меняется с -1 до 1 (два полных круга),  получается что маска наложена на изображение 2 раза: 1 раз - прозрачность, 2 раз - она же
                // поэтому увеличивается наложенность, белый цвет. В итоге при изменении с -1 до 1 ушла бы в начале белизна, а потом провернулась бы маска,
                // и не обрезалась бы
                float oAtan2MaskRotatable = oRotatorNormalized - oAtan2MaskNormalized;
                float oWhiteToBlackMask = ceil(oAtan2MaskRotatable);                
                // Финальная прозрачность 
                float oFinalMultiply = _MainTex_var.a * max(oAtan2MaskNormalized, ceil(oWhiteToBlackMask)); 

                /*** Излучение (Emissive) ***/
                // oFinalMultiply чтоб обрезать прозрачную область, где она обрезана в самой текстуре
                float3 finalColor = _MainTex_var.rgb * _Color.rgb * oFinalMultiply;
                // Конечный результат (цвет, обработанный маской и повернутый под углом альфа канал)
                return fixed4(finalColor, oFinalMultiply);
            }

            ENDCG
        }       
    }

    FallBack "Diffuse"    
}
```

Чтобы в нужный момент запустить заливку, конечно же нужно дать команду. А откуда её можно дать? Правильно — из скрипта. Он будет расположен ниже:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class RadialFill : MonoBehaviour {

    public float cutoffStartAngle = 5.0f; // градусы 
    public float opacityStartAngle = -350.0f; // градусы,  -2 * PI + 10 (небольшой начальный угол)
    public float deltaAngle = 5f;

    private const float MAX_ANGLE = 360.0f;

    private Material material;
    private float _TextureRotator; // ссылка на переменную _TextureRotator в шейдере
    private float _OpacityRotator; // ссылка на переменную _TextureRotator в шейдере

    void Start () {
        material = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
    }


    void Update () {            
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))       
            StartCoroutine(FillSprite());       
    }


    IEnumerator FillSprite() {      
        var cOffStart = cutoffStartAngle;
        var oStart = opacityStartAngle;

        material.SetFloat("_TextureRotator", cOffStart);
        material.SetFloat("_OpacityRotator", oStart);
        _TextureRotator = cOffStart;
        _OpacityRotator = oStart;

        while(_OpacityRotator <= MAX_ANGLE) {           
            if (_TextureRotator >= MAX_ANGLE) 
                _TextureRotator = MAX_ANGLE;
            if (_OpacityRotator >= MAX_ANGLE) 
                _OpacityRotator = MAX_ANGLE;

            material.SetFloat("_TextureRotator", _TextureRotator);
            material.SetFloat("_OpacityRotator", _OpacityRotator);

            _OpacityRotator += deltaAngle;
            _TextureRotator += deltaAngle;

            yield return null;
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

где:

`cutoffStartAngle` — начальный угол обрезки, `opacityStartAngle` — начальный угол прозрачности. Эти параметры для того, чтобы немного отрегулировать по вкусу площадь сектора, занимаемого прозрачностью. Замечу, что прозрачность изменяется от -360 до 360, потому что первый круг она проворачивается сама по себе, а второй круг — плавно "заходит" за текстуру.

`deltaAngle` - дельта, на которую проворачиваются маски.

**Что скрипт делает?** При нажатии нажатии на клавишу мыши он берет шейдер у спрайта (точнее с его материала), устанавливает изначальные углы, в цикле изменяет угол поворота и передает это значение в шейдер, чтобы он там уже у себя применил значения в `frag`.

Выглядит в инспекторе так:

[image: RadialFillShader&Script inspector]

- Opacity Rotator - вращение маски прозрачности
- Texture Rotator - вращение маски обрезки
- Fill Clockwise - по часовой стрелке или против
- Fill Origin - с какой стороны начинать (справа/слева/сверху/снизу)

Итог будет выглядеть примерно таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увы на данной гифке не получается передать то, как это выглядит в правильности

---

#### Улучшение

- Так как у секции *cutoff* и *opacity* есть общие части, то их можно вынести в общие функции, как и во всех нормальных языках программирования.

  ```
  Shader "Custom/RadialFillCommonFunctions" {
      Properties {
          [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("MainTex", 2D) = "white" {}
          _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
          _OpacityRotator ("Opacity Rotator", Range(-360, 360)) = -360 // два полных оборота
          _TextureRotator ("Texture Rotator", Range(0, 360)) = 360
          [MaterialToggle] _FillClockwise ("Fill Clockwise", Float ) = 1
          [HideInInspector]_Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
          [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0    
          [KeywordEnum(Right, Bottom, Left, Top)] _Fill_Origin("Fill Origin", Int) = 0        
      }

      SubShader {
          Tags {
              "IgnoreProjector"="True"
              "Queue"="Transparent"
              "RenderType"="Transparent"
              "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
              "PreviewType"="Plane"
          }

          Pass {
              Name "FORWARD"
              Tags {
                  "LightMode"="ForwardBase"
              }

              Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
              Cull Off
              ZWrite Off

              CGPROGRAM
              #pragma vertex vert
              #pragma fragment frag
              #define UNITY_PASS_FORWARDBASE
              #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON

              #pragma shader_feature _FILL_ORIGIN_RIGHT _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM _FILL_ORIGIN_LEFT _FILL_ORIGIN_TOP

              #include "UnityCG.cginc"
              #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase
              #pragma exclude_renderers gles3 metal d3d11_9x xbox360 xboxone ps3 ps4 psp2 
              #pragma target 3.0

              static const float TAU = float(6.283185); // это 2 * PI, кто не знает

              uniform sampler2D _MainTex; 
              uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
              uniform float4 _Color;
              uniform float _OpacityRotator;
              uniform float _TextureRotator;
              uniform fixed _FillClockwise;       

              struct VertexInput {
                  float4 vertex : POSITION;
                  float3 normal : NORMAL;
                  float4 tangent : TANGENT;
                  float2 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
              };

              struct VertexOutput {
                  float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                  float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                  float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
                  float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD2;
                  float3 tangentDir : TEXCOORD3;
                  float3 bitangentDir : TEXCOORD4;
              };

              // матрица вращения
              float2x2 getMatrix(float angle) {                               
                  float r_cos = cos(angle);
                  float r_sin = sin(angle);                
                  return float2x2(r_cos, -r_sin, r_sin, r_cos);
              }

              // формирование маски
              float2x2 getMask(float oAtan2MaskNormalized, float rotator, int isRotatorSubtract) {
                  //float atan2var = reverseMaskCoords ? atan2(maskChannels.r, maskChannels.g) : atan2(maskChannels.g, maskChannels.r);
                  //float oAtan2MaskNormalized = (atan2var / TAU) + 0.5;              
                  float oAtan2MaskRotatable = isRotatorSubtract ? oAtan2MaskNormalized - rotator : rotator - oAtan2MaskNormalized;
                  return ceil(oAtan2MaskRotatable);
              }

              float getNormalizedAtanMask(float2 maskChannels, int reverseMaskCoords) {
                  float atan2var = reverseMaskCoords ? atan2(maskChannels.r, maskChannels.g) : atan2(maskChannels.g, maskChannels.r);
                  return (atan2var / TAU) + 0.5;
              }

              VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                  VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                  o.uv0 = v.texcoord0;
                  o.normalDir = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                  o.tangentDir = normalize(mul(_Object2World, float4(v.tangent.xyz, 0.0)).xyz);
                  o.bitangentDir = normalize(cross(o.normalDir, o.tangentDir) * v.tangent.w);
                  o.posWorld = mul(_Object2World, v.vertex);
                  o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex );
                  #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                      o.pos = UnityPixelSnap(o.pos);
                  #endif

                  return o;
              }

              float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                  i.normalDir = normalize(i.normalDir);                
                  float4 _MainTex_var = tex2D(_MainTex,TRANSFORM_TEX(i.uv0, _MainTex));                

                  /*** Общее начало для opacity и cutoff, помогающее переключать вращение по/против часовой стрелки BEGIN ***/
                  // float2(1, -1) - по часовой, float2(1, 1) - против часовой
                  float2 clockCounterDirection = _FillClockwise ? float2(1, -1) : float2(1, 1); 
                  // по умолчанию "обрезание" начинается слева. 
                  // умножение на -1 для того, чтоб началось справа.....просто потому, что я так хочу =)
                  float2 CommonStartAndSwitcher = (-1 * (i.uv0 - 0.5)) * clockCounterDirection;
                  /*** Общее начало для opacity и cutoff с переключателем вращения по/против часовой стрелки END ***/


                  /*** Секция для cutoff ***/
                  float tRotatorNormalized = _TextureRotator / 360.0; 
                  float cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = 1.0; // изменение направления

                  #if _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM
                      cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = _FillClockwise ? 1.75 : 1.25;
                  #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_LEFT
                      cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = 1.5;
                  #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_TOP
                      cutoffRightBottomLeftTop = _FillClockwise ? 1.25 : 1.75;
                  #endif
                  cutoffRightBottomLeftTop += 0.001;

                  float cutoffRotator_ang = cutoffRightBottomLeftTop * -TAU;
                  float2x2 cutoffRotationMatrix = getMatrix(cutoffRotator_ang); 
                  float2 cutoffRotator = mul(CommonStartAndSwitcher, cutoffRotationMatrix);
                  float whiteToBlackMask = getMask(getNormalizedAtanMask(cutoffRotator, 0), tRotatorNormalized, 1);
                  // Финальная маска
                  float finalMask = 1.0 - whiteToBlackMask;
                  clip(finalMask - 0.5);


                  /*** Секция для opacity ***/
                  float oRotatorNormalized = _OpacityRotator / 360.0;
                  float2 oVector = float2(1, -1);
                  float oRightBottomLeftTop = 1.0;
                  int reverseMaskCoords = 0;
                  #if (_FILL_ORIGIN_TOP || _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM)
                      reverseMaskCoords = 1;
                  #endif

                  #if _FILL_ORIGIN_LEFT
                      oVector = float2(-1, 1);
                  #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_TOP
                      oVector = _FillClockwise ? float2(-1, -1) : float2(1, 1);
                      oRightBottomLeftTop = -1.0;
                  #elif _FILL_ORIGIN_BOTTOM
                      oVector = _FillClockwise ? float2(1, 1) : float2(-1, -1);
                      oRightBottomLeftTop = -1.0;
                  #endif

                  float oRotator_ang = oRightBottomLeftTop * (oRotatorNormalized * -TAU);
                  float2x2 oRotationMatrix = getMatrix(oRotator_ang);             
                  float2 oRotator = mul(oVector * CommonStartAndSwitcher, oRotationMatrix);
                  float oWhiteToBlackMask = getMask(getNormalizedAtanMask(oRotator, reverseMaskCoords), oRotatorNormalized, 0);                                                                   
                  // Финальная прозрачность 
                  float oFinalMultiply = _MainTex_var.a * max(getNormalizedAtanMask(oRotator, reverseMaskCoords), ceil(oWhiteToBlackMask)); 


                  /*** Излучение (Emissive) ***/
                  // oFinalMultiply чтоб обрезать прозрачную область, где она обрезана в самой текстуре
                  float3 finalColor = _MainTex_var.rgb * _Color.rgb * oFinalMultiply;
                  // Конечный результат (цвет, обработанный маской и повернутый под углом альфа канал)
                  return fixed4(finalColor, oFinalMultiply);
              }

              ENDCG
          }       
      }

      FallBack "Diffuse"    
  }
  ```

Comment: Вот это ответ))) спасибо большое))сегодня попробую обязательно, у меня была еще такая проблема странная. Попробовал в shader forge собрать. Добился нужного эффекта, в итоге в Юнити в окне инспектора все норм, а в непосредственно game, просто эффект фэйда на весь объект. Звучит непонятно понимаю, прикреплю гиф сейчас покажу.

Comment: @justyx к сожалению проблемой метода в ответе - является равномерная маска. В теории, как я описал, надо бы маску сделать в виде текстуры и работать с ней. Ведь вручную маску можно уже сделать более плотной по белому или черному цвету, что позволило бы еще больше проконтролировать площадь прозрачности и её переход. Вот правда с текстурой чёт пока не заладилось.............. а ну и невозможность работы с мультиспрайтами, как это делает Canvas UI. Там алгоритм дофига большой нужен.

Comment: Сейчас буду читать вникать. я добавил там апдейт в описание.

Comment: @justyx а можешь код из ShaderForge куда-либо выложить? Посмотреть что там. Покопаться. Правда Не знаю на сколько быстрый ответ от меня ожидать ))) ............. а я что-то не вижу тот эффект, который ты в вопросе описывал)) ни блюра ни радиальной обрезки)

Comment: да я потому и указал что это один ИЗ  требуемых эффектов. их было 5. радиальный, вертикальны, через вспышку и тд. Но у всех особенность плавного вот такого "поведения". При этом данный эффект на гиф я уже плюнул на блюр и попытался просто реализовать эффект как стандартный image в unity (заполнение сверху вниз), только с плавным фэйдом. Код сейчас поищу. Не уверен что смогу вот так сходу найти. Но сегодня найду.

Comment: @justyx а так вопрос...... в итоге эффект то надо было накладывать на что? на весь экран или чисто на спрайт? или что-то на спрайт, а что-то на весь экран? я что-то потерялся во всём......совсем присовсем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50911/discussion-between-justyx-and--).