# Как сделать прозрачным часть изображения?

Tags: c#, unity3d, изображения, ui

Есть скролл (Scroll Rect) с изображениями (Image), который можно проматывать вверх / внинз:

[image: концепт: скролл с изображениями]

как видно на примере выше - когда проматываешь скролл например вверх и изображение выходит за пределы скролла (или экрана-не важно) оно должно плавно - частями уходить в прозрачность, соответственно за этим изображением видно фон

есть ли возможность реализовать подобное на Unity, а конкретно можно ли сделать только часть изображения прозрачным?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585862/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-unity3d

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко,то нам нужно использовать спрайт маску для прозрачности изображения по краям

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIwe34Fg0As

На видео все показано:

1.есть 2 изображения 1 из списка и второе полностью черное

2.на черное навешиваем sprite mask
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3.у картинок из списка меняем слой на -1(либо он должен быть на 1 меньше чем маски)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4.ставим параметр mask interaction -> visible inside mask

5.меняем у маски ее прозрачность(в параметре цвет,кроме rgb есть альфа канал отвечающий за прозрачность)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а с UI Image все это как то подружить получится?

Comment: @animagnoa прозрачной будет только та часть картинки которая будет под маской